# Crash: IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-5.0-lollipop

I am getting a crash at startup when launching the activity.

Stack Trace:

```
main Process: com.haziqhussain.hazgames, PID: 10248 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.haziqhussain.hazgames/com.haziqhussain.hazgames.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
```

Comment: do you have `proguard-rules.pro` in your project? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes it is I'm my app folder and the error is making the app crash on launch.

Comment: @HaziqHussain can you post the stack trace of crash?

Comment: @AsifMujteba I think this is it: main
    Process: com.haziqhussain.hazgames, PID: 10248
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.haziqhussain.hazgames/com.haziqhussain.hazgames.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)

Comment: @AsifMujteba at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear, since you are using `ActionBarActivity` so you need to use `Theme.AppCompat` or its descendant theme for this activity. or better use it for the whole application. Open your `AndroidManifest.xml` and edit one of these tags:

Add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to `application` tag for applying this theme on all activities or for applying to a specific activity add it to that `activity` tag.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but when I click the button to go to the next activity it crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: @HaziqHussain if the stack trace is same, than you need to do the same thing, else please create a new question with the stack trace and i'll review it! Since this problem is fixed now, you might also want to follow this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work